# 3D vector line from a point and a directional vector

Tags: python, vector, line, intersection, plane

I am trying to get a 3D line using a point on the line P(0) and directional vector V

I found SymPy has libraries to obtain lines using two points but not with vector and point. Is there any way that I can get the line as an object?

My final motive is to find the intersection between that line and the plane.
This is my code so far

```
import numpy as np

from sympy import Plane, Line3D, Point3D #it's not needed here

#plane Points
a1 = Point3D (-5,15,-5)
a2 = Point3D (5,15,-5)
a3 = Point3D (5,15,5)
#line Points
p0 = Point3D (0,3,1) #point in line
v0 = [0, 1 ,1] #line direction as vector

#create plane and line
plane = Plane(a1,a2,a3)

line = # Need to find the line


print(f"plane equation: {plane.equation()}")
print(f"line equation: {line.equation()}")

#find intersection:

intr = plane.intersection(line)

intersection =np.array(intr[0],dtype=float)
print(f"intersection: {intersection}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After carefully going through the libraries I was able to find out the answer to the question.

When you have Line ( direction ratio) v0 and point on vector p0 the following method can be used to obtain the 3D line vector.

`line = Line3D(p0,direction_ratio=v0)`
Hence the complete code will be.

````
from sympy import Plane, Line3D, Point3D 

#plane Points
a1 = Point3D (-5,15,-5)
a2 = Point3D (5,15,-5)
a3 = Point3D (5,15,5)
#line Points
p0 = Point3D (0,3,1) #point in line
v0 = [0, 1 ,1] #line direction as vector

#create plane and line
plane = Plane(a1,a2,a3)

line = Line3D(p0,direction_ratio=v0)


print(f"plane equation: {plane.equation()}")
print(f"line equation: {line.equation()}")

#find intersection:

intr = plane.intersection(line)

intersection =np.array(intr[0],dtype=float)
print(f"intersection: {intersection}")```
````